# SharePoint 2010 100% CPU Usage AreaTemplateSettings.aspx

Tags: 2010, error

Whenever I try to go to "Page layouts and site templates" (AreaTemplateSettings.aspx) in Site Settings, the w3wp process spikes to 100% on my SharePoint server and the page never loads.

Eventually I see "An unexpected error has occurred" (after about 5 minutes) and the following logged in ULS:

```
SOAP exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.     at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()     at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)     at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtilityInternal.SendResponse(HttpContext context, Int32 code, String strBody)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtilityInternal.Send404(HttpContext context)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SPBaseImpl.get_Site()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.ListDataImpl.GetReplicaId()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.ListDataImpl.GetListItemChangesSinceTokenCore(String strListName, String strViewName, String strQuery, String strViewFields, String strRowLimit, String strQueryOptions, String strChangeToken, String strContains, SyncKnowledge knowledge, String strSyncScope, Boolean useKnowledge)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.ListDataImpl.GetListItemChangesSinceToken(String strListName, String strViewName, String strQuery, String strViewFields, String strRowLimit, String strQueryOptions, String strChangeToken, String strContains)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.ListDataValidatorImpl.GetListItemChangesSinceToken(String strListName, String strViewName, String strQuery, String strViewFields, String strRowLimit, String strQueryOptions, String strChangeToken, String strContains)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.Lists.GetListItemChangesSinceToken(String listName, String viewName, SoapXmlElement query, SoapXmlElement viewFields, String rowLimit, SoapXmlElement queryOptions, String changeToken, SoapXmlElement contains)
```

Being that this error doesn't help much in figuring out the problem, I used Visual Studio and attached a remote debugger to the w3wp process, then tried hitting the page in my browser.

I see the following exception:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
  Message=List does not exist.

```
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
  Source=""
  ErrorCode=-2130575322
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)
  InnerException:
```

Stack Trace:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(string bstrUrl, System.Guid foreignWebId, string bstrListInternalName, int dwBaseType, int dwBaseTypeAlt, int dwServerTemplate, uint dwGetListFlags, uint dwListFilterFlags, bool bPrefetchMetaData, bool bSecurityTrimmed, bool bGetSecurityData, bool bPrefetchRelatedFields, Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, out int plRecycleBinCount) + 0x116 bytes  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(System.Guid webId, string strListName) + 0x26f bytes 
    Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.Count.get() + 0x70 bytes 
    Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetUniqueListByTemplateType(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType type) + 0x3c bytes   
    Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.GetCatalog(Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType typeCatalog, bool bWithEnum) + 0x9c bytes   
    Microsoft.SharePoint.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.GetCustomWebTemplates(uint LCID) + 0x2b bytes  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.InitializeSiteTemplatePicker() + 0x228 bytes   
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.InitializeSiteTemplatesSection() + 0xf3 bytes  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.OnLoad(System.EventArgs e) + 0x12f bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() + 0x42 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0x97c bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0xa0 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() + 0x5b bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0xf0 bytes   
    App_Web_areatemplatesettings.aspx.2a428413.r5ux01zz.dll!ASP._layouts_areatemplatesettings_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x9 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x257 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) + 0xab bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x511 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) + 0x72 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x269 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x411 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x2b bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x540 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x2b bytes    
    [Appdomain Transition]
```

(note that it says App_Web_areatemplatesettings.aspx)...then the w3wp starts to churn...and if I pause, I find it stuck around

```
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Guid.ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider) + 0x61 bytes  
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObject.ParentID.get() + 0x61 bytes    
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedArea.GetEffectiveAvailablePageLayoutsString(Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedObjectFactory factory) + 0x9d bytes 
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.InitializePageLayoutPicker() + 0x38a bytes 
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.InitializePageLayoutsSection() + 0x11a bytes   
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll!Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.AreaTemplateSettingsPage.OnLoad(System.EventArgs e) + 0x137 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() + 0x42 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0x97c bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) + 0xa0 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() + 0x5b bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0xf0 bytes   
    App_Web_areatemplatesettings.aspx.2a428413.r5ux01zz.dll!ASP._layouts_areatemplatesettings_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x9 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x257 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) + 0xab bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x511 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) + 0x72 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x269 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x411 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x2b bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x540 bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x2b bytes    
    [Appdomain Transition]
```

Any idea what to do here?

This site was previously a sub-site that was converted into a top level site collection (I imagine that has something to do with the problem)...

Answer (score -1):

This guy's tool fixed it:

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/convert-a-sub-site-to-a-site-collection/

Comment: The guy in question being Gary Lapointe :-)  and the tool being a PowerShell script, as one would expect.